# T-SQL Using CTE to aggregate totals for matching and non-matching periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Matched Sales are provided by the join, It's getting the unmatched that is eluding me.

```
CTE
With PriorSalesCTE
    (
    Item
Variant,
    Sum(sales)
    Date between 7/1/2020 and 7/5/2020
),
    CurrentSalesCTE
(
    Item
Variant,
    Sum(sales)
    Date between 7/1/2021 and 7/5/2021
)
Select 
SUM(cs.Sales) ‘MatchedSales’
FROM PriorSalesCTE ps join CurrentSalesCTE ps
    ON cs.Item = ps.Item
    And cs.Variant = ps.Variant
```

Now I need the empty spaces on both sides
I need the sales for items sold in 2020 but not sold in 2021 – **Lost Sales**
Conversely, sales for 2021 that did not sell in 2020 – **New Sales**.

I tried adding these in the CTE as separate sections of the CTE, but the join doesn’t give me what I need.

Any suggestions?  Is the CTE simply preventing me for getting everything and maybe add a UNION ALL query to get the unmatched values?

Comment: Are you looking for a `FULL JOIN`? [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: You can get both in a single run using a conditional aggregation.  What is your DBMS?

Comment: Please TAG your specific RDBMS, your CTE is not a valid syntax I'm aware of.

Comment: Also, just to check you understand how Stack Overflow works, is there any reason you have not accepted any answers to your previous questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your actual query, you could use a `FULL JOIN`, which will give you the results from either side also.

---

But I think there is another solution: you don't need to join separate queries for this, you can just use conditional aggregation

```sql
WITH SalesByItem AS (
    SELECT
      t.Item,
      t.Variant
      Sales2020 = SUM(CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN '20200701' and '20200705' THEN t.Sales END),
      Sales2021 = SUM(CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN '20210701' and '20210705' THEN t.Sales END)
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE (Date BETWEEN '20200701' and '20200705'
        OR Date BETWEEN '20210701' and '20210705')
    GROUP BY
      t.Item,
      t.Variant
)
SELECT
  NewSales = SUM(CASE WHEN Sales2020 IS NULL THEN Sales2021 END),
  MatchedSales = SUM(CASE WHEN Sales2020 IS NOT NULL AND Sales2021 IS NOT NULL THEN Sales2021 END),
  LostSales = SUM(CASE WHEN Sales2021 IS NULL THEN Sales2020 END)
FROM SalesByItem s;
```